# Listbox customize selector bounding box

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Hello Stackoverflowers,

In the following Listbox, the selection box when i mouse over an element goes from the top left of the window to bottom right of the element. This is a problem both for esthetics and for mouse event on the Canvas in ListBox.ItemsPanel.

I would like to know if it's possible to make the selection box at the shape of the element inside (same shape and starting at the element coordinates instead of top left).

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OverlayElements}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
             Background="Transparent">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#33FF0000"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:EllipseOverlayElement}">
                <Path Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry
                            Center="{Binding Center}"
                            RadiusX="{Binding RadiusX}"
                            RadiusY="{Binding RadiusY}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:LineOverlayElement}">
                <Path Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <LineGeometry
                            StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}"
                            EndPoint="{Binding EndPoint}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

Tell me if i'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - Are you sure you want to use Canvas inside your ItemsPanelTemplate. I guess Canvas is causing this issue.

you can simply use a Stackpanel to lay items vertically and using Datatemplate u can include either an Elipse or rectangle. This way you will have an shape in confined space.

Let me know if it works.

Thanks, vishal

Comment: The purpose of this is to draw shapes. So the canvas is here to be able to draw anywhere without order or relation between elements. The list is here to represent an observable collection of polymorphic elements in the ViewModel.

Comment: Can you provide me your viewmodels details also, so that i can replicate the scenario?